# VB.NET DataGridView Columns Change after loading data

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am working with a VB.Net winform and datagrid. I am dynamically creating the datagridview columns and setting the data property. Here is part of the code that creates the datagrid view.

```
MyDataGrid.ColumnCount = 13

        MyDataGrid.Columns(0).Name = "MRN"
        MyDataGrid.Columns(0).HeaderText = "MRN"
        MyDataGrid.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "med_rec_nbr"

        MyDataGrid.Columns(1).Name = "LastName"
        MyDataGrid.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Last Name"
        MyDataGrid.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "last_name"

        MyDataGrid.Columns(2).Name = "FirstName"
        MyDataGrid.Columns(2).HeaderText = "First Name"
        MyDataGrid.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "first_name"

        MyDataGrid.Columns(3).Name = "DateOfBirth"
        MyDataGrid.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Date of Birth"
        MyDataGrid.Columns(3).DataPropertyName = "date_of_birth"
```

After setting the datasource to a datatable from SQL Server source, the columns change. Here is the code where I set the datasource.

```
Dim dtResults As DataTable
                dtResults = GetSQLData(ID)

                MyDataGrid.DataSource = dtResults
```

Here is a before picture.

[image]

Here is the after loading the datatable

[image]

The weird thing is, I have other DataGridViews and they are not behaving like this at all.
Why are the columns changing? What should I look for? Is there a property i should look for?

Comment: Do you have AutoGenerateColumns tuned on for this datagridview?

Comment: Why create the columns in code rather than in the designer?

Comment: What is the order of columns and their names in your `DataTable`? Does it match the "after" image?

Comment: Are you aware that declaring a variable on one line and then assigning to it on the next is needlessly verbose? You can just use `Dim dtResults As DataTable = GetSQLData(ID)` or, if the return type of that method is `DataTable`, use `Dim dtResults = GetSQLData(ID)`. Unless you're using that variable elsewhere, you could even just use `MyDataGrid.DataSource = GetSQLData(ID)`. That said, you probably ought to be using a `BindingSource` between the table and the grid.

Comment: Actually you created dynamic columns are not reflect after bind the data from data table. What actually is , what order in datatable, that order bind finally.

Comment: I set AutoGeneratedColumns to false, that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you created dynamic columns are not reflect after bind the data from data table. What actually is , what order in datatable result, that order bind finally.
Better in select query you change the order and which columns need and then bind in datagridview.And also use DataBindings.

```
MyDataGrid.DataSource = dtResults
MyDataGrid.DataBindings()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = False
```